# Regex to get length of group of character classes

Tags: regex

I have a workaround for this, but was hoping to find a purely regex solution.

The requirements are:

- has one required character
- only pulls from a pool of approved characters
- minimum length of 4
- single word, no whitespace

e.g.
required character: **m**
pool of characters: **[a,b,e,l]**

Possible matches:
mabel
abemal
labeam

won't match:
a mael
ama
label

So far I have this expression, but putting a {4,} after it thinks I'm talking about multiplying word matches by 4.
`^\b(?:[abel]*[m]+[abel]*)\b`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use

```
^(?=.*[m])[abelm]{4,}$
```

> `^` start of a line or string
>
> Positive Lookahead `(?=.*[m])`
> Asserts that the string contains at least 1 `m` character
>
> `[abelm]{4,}` matches characters in the list `abelm`
> between 4 and unlimited times, as many times as possible.
> (greedy) (case sensitive)
>
> `$` end of a line or string

Comment: I don't think I totally understood how the positive lookahead worked before, but this did it - thank you!